# Дан текст. Нужно поменять регистр букв после точки

Tags: c++, строки, stl

Исходный текст набран с ошибками . Вывести исходный текст, заменив в нем строчные(малые) буквы, следующие за точкой и произвольным количеством пробелов на прописные(большие) буквы. В исходном тексте может быть много предложений и точек. А также вычислить количество слов «ПК». (не использовать find)

```
string first{"the problem wasn't Dulce or his father.to discover and define those laws is the problem of history.it's a big problem. i.i.ivanov"};
cout << first;

decltype(first.cbegin()) iter;
size_t position = 0;
auto mPos = first.size();
while (mPos<first.size())
{
    iter = find(first.cbegin(), first.cend(), '.');
    position = distance(first.cbegin(), iter) + 1;
    transform(first.cbegin(), first.cend(), first.cbegin() + position, ::tolower(iter));
}
```

'

Answer (score 2):

Проще пройтись чем-то типа конечного автомата...

```
string s{"the problem wasn't Dulce or his father.   to discover and define those laws is the problem of history.it's a big problem. i.i.ivanov"};
cout << s << endl;

for(size_t state = 0, i = 0; s[i]; ++i)
{
    switch(state)
    {
    case 0:
        if (s[i] != '.') break;
        state = 1;
        break;
    case 1:
        if (s[i] == ' ' || s[i] == '.') break;
        s[i] = toupper(s[i]);
        state = 0;
        break;
    }
}
cout << s << endl;
```

Если нужно менять и самый первый символ -

```
for(size_t state = 1, i = 0; s[i]; ++i)
```

Можно без `switch` - даже короче:

```
for(size_t state = 1, i = 0; s[i]; ++i)
{
    if (state)
    {
        if (s[i] != ' ' && s[i] != '.')
        {
            s[i] = toupper(s[i]);
            state = !state;
        }
    } else if (s[i] == '.') state = !state;
}
```

Количество слов сами допишете? :)